# Run python script in GCP that use firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm having an app that stores all the data (images and video) in Firebase storage.
I have to do some image processing on it, and wonder about a GCP platform that enables running the python script that uses the Firebase storage without downloading the files (to the server that runs the script).

In other words- a platform that enables run scripts on one server while using files from different servers.

Note- I'm using now pyrebase for Firebase API

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, you can process the files from Firebase storage with Python if you use the google-cloud-storage package. Documentation can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.storage). The code still downloads the files in the background, however, you do not need to actually copy the files to where your script runs.

To answer your main question: where can you run this Python script? There are several serverless options within the Google Cloud Platform where you can run Python scripts, without having to worry about the underlying infrastructure.

One could use:

- Cloud Functions
- Cloud Run
- App Engine

It depends on how often you want this workload to run and how big the files are. Cloud Functions are pretty easy to use, and you can schedule a cloud function to run at a certain time. You could also choose to trigger a Cloud Function when a file arrives in Google Cloud Storage, which is in some situations very powerful. However, the limitation of Cloud Functions is 2GB and 900 seconds of runtime. If you would somehow go over those limitations, because the files are very big or processing lasts longer than 9 minutes, you could choose Cloud Run or even App Engine. They offer long runtimes and a higher memory/CPU limit.

If need more processing power, serverless may not be the best option for you. Then you could choose Dataproc or Dataflow, which are capable of processing "Big Data".